# Basis of $\text{sl}(3,\mathbb C)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I would like to have a basis of $sl(3,\mathbb C)$, the 3 times 3 matrices with complex entries such that their trace is zero. I know that this vector space is 8-dimensional but I struggle in finding an explicit basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basis for the vector space of traceless $3\times 3$ matrices is given by the six matrices $E_{ij}$ for $1\le i,j\le 3$ with $i\neq j$ and the $2$ matrices $E_{11}-E_{22}$ and $E_{22}-E_{33}$. Here $E_{ij}$ denotes the matrix having entry $1$ at the position $(i,j)$ and zero entries otherwise. So altogether we have eight basis elements, namely $$E_{12},E_{13},E_{21},E_{23},E_{31},E_{32}, E_{11}-E_{22},E_{22}-E_{33}.$$
The last two basis vectors are a basis of the Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$.