# Exponential of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In Fulton and Harris 'Representation Theory: A first course', page 150, we have the following paragraph

"Observe that when we exponentiate the image of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ under the embedding $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}(\mathbb{C})$ corresponding to the representation $\text{Sym}^nV$, we arrive at the group $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ when $n$ is odd and $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ when $n$ is even."

Now I am not sure how to explicitely find this embedding, and I cannot see how it is evident that we get different groups depending on the parity of $n$. Can someone explain to me how one can see that?

Comment: $\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}(\mathbb{C})$ has several copies of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$, which gives the embeddings you ask for.

Comment: Start small... try $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ case first, write down a basis as in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809683/basis-of-textsl3-mathbb-c and see can you think of two different embeddings of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ into $\mathfrak{sl}_3$

Comment: If $H$, $X$ and $Y$ are the standard basis of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ as in Fulton and Harris, two different such embeddings would take H in the upper left or in the lower right "corner" of a 3x3 matrix with all other entries zero. But I still do not see how this leads two those two different groups as the exponent image.

Comment: @S.Farr: Those two embeddings are really basically the same. But what about the embedding that goes in all the corners, leaving the middle "cross" free?